# Why does a websocket disconnect on IE 10? - I'm using play framework 2 - Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, websocket, playframework-2.0, akka

I am opening a web socket connection using play framework 2.3 with Akka actor 2.3.9.
It works fine with many browsers except for IE (10 and higher), after a while the connection closes with error code **1003** and error message **"This WebSocket does not handle frames of that type"**.

I found this message in play framework on this class:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-netty-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/netty/WebSocketHandler.scala

Also an exception thrown on server side: **java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException**

Is there a specific configuration when open web socket on IE 10 to keep the connection alive? or shall I do something on play configuration?

I tried to set web socket close timeout on IE as in here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#websocket_closetimeout

but it doesn't work either.

Note: I am loading the view using [Ajax Routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting)

here are my sample code:

view:

```
if ("WebSocket" in window){
    var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket;
    var socket = new WS("@controllers.routes.MyController.socket().webSocketURL(request)");

    var receiveEvent = function(event) {
        if(event != undefined && event.data != undefined){
          var jsonData = JSON.parse(event.data);
          console.log("[.] a : ", jsonData.a);
          console.log("[.] b : ", jsonData.b);
          //do my changes in view
        }
    }

    socket.onmessage = receiveEvent;

    var opentime, closetime;
    socket.onopen = function(){
        opentime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log("Connection opened at :", opentime);
    };

    socket.onclose = function(event){
        closetime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(event.code);
        console.log(event.reason);

        alert("Connection is closed at : ", closetime);
        console.log("[.] socket lived for (in milli seconds) : ", closetime - opentime);
    };

    socket.onerror = function(error){
        alert(error);
    };

} else {
    // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
    alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
}
```

controller:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

  public static WebSocket<String> socket() {
      return WebSocket.withActor(new Function<ActorRef, Props>() {
          public Props apply(ActorRef out) throws Throwable {
              return MyWebSocketActor.props(out);
          }
      });
  }
}
```

actor:

```
public class MyWebSocketActor extends UntypedActor {

    public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
        return Props.create(MyWebSocketActor.class, out);
    }

    private final ActorRef out;

    public MyWebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

      if (message instanceof MyEvent) {
            MyEvent me = (MyEvent)message;

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            try{
                jo.put("a", me.getA());
                jo.put("b", me.getB());
            } catch (JSONException e){
                Logger.error("Class:MyWebSocketActor Method:onReceive, error:JSON format error");
            }

            if(out != null){
                out.tell(jo.toString(), self());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

exception thrown on server side:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:433)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:128)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:59)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.writeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:292)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:254)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:704)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:671)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:248)
        at play.core.server.netty.WebSocketHandler$$anon$1.closeWebSocket(WebSocketHandler.scala:118)
        at play.core.server.netty.WebSocketHandler$$anon$1.messageReceived(WebSocketHandler.scala:88)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:64)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:138)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: For starters, your client code should select `WebSocket` (if it exists) over `mozWebSocket` not the other way around.  Use the industry standard interface if it exists and only fall back to another interface is the standard one doesn't exist.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, Thanks. But many samples do this. I removed the check and used 'WebSocket' only and nothing changed.